# Pending/mined transaction dapp UI feedback using Metamask?

Tags: web3js, contract-design, dapp-development, metamask

So I have deployed a smart contract and can interact with it via a web UI using `web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address)` and Metamask - so far so good.

However, between a transaction being submitted and it being mined I would like to display one message and once it has been mined another one.

I understand that `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash).blockNumber == ""` until the tx has been mined. But how do I check this until it has in fact been mined using javascript and the injected web3 from Metamask?

EDIT: I am trying to make it work with promises but just can't wrap my head around how to implement it. This is my code that should handle a transaction receipt via a promise:

```
function approveFactoryContract(factory) {
  factoryAdress = $("#factory").val();
  RegistratContractInstance.approveFactoryContract(factoryAdress, false, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}, function(error, result){
           if(!error)
               console.log(result),
               $("#message").html("Approval request has been submitted - please wait a moment for it to be mined. You can check your transaction <a href=\"https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/"+result+"\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>");
           else
               console.error(error);
       });
}
```

How do I make this work?

Display text while pending: Please wait for your transaction to be mined.
Display text when resolved: Your transaction has been mined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this.

This library is useful. It gives you a Promise for the mined transaction, so you can carry on after you know it's mined, update the UI etc.

https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6

In practice, I've found that I'm always setting up event listeners to watch for updates *from anyone* and then if that information has an impact on the display, updating the relevant fields. It leads to nice dynamic updates on so-called static web pages.

I've observed that when that sort of thing is in place, I don't *need* to be concerned about mined transactions from *this* user because I'm already watching for updates from *any* user. If something happens that impacts a field, message, style etc. on the screen, the callback deals with it.

There's a hidden requirement here. Every important state change that unfolds in the contract will fire an event emission that will describe everything important about the state change. I would argue it's a best pratice to do that. Among other benefits, having that in place is certainly convenient at the UI construction stage.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Triggering an event handler for *every* event sounds fairly excessive. Imagine that "best practice" for an ICO page with thousands of TXs. I'd be hesitant calling this a general best practice. IMO that's why we have filters and topics to selectively subscribe to.

Comment: @ValidityLabs-Sebastian. I don't disagree with you, so possibly misstated my meaning. Trying to say contracts should emit an event. Clients can selectively listen but there has to be something to listen for.